# Converting between unknown derived types at runtime

Tags: c#

Lets say I have an abstract base class used for polymorphism and I like to write a method to convert one derived type to another, but I don't know either of the derived types at compile time. I believe reflection would be the right way to solve this, but I'm not sure what the correct way to implement it would be. Here's where I'm currently stuck.

```
Public Static BaseClass ConvertTo(BaseClass bc, Type type) {
    //bc is currently DerivedClass1 which implements IConvertable
    //type is currently DerivedClass2
    //Trying to convert DerivedClass1 to DerivedClass2
    return (BaseClass)ChangeType(bc, type);
}
```

This method will convert DerivedClass1 to DerivedClass2 but I had to Implement the IConvertable Interface for DerivedClass1 for it to work, which I'm unhappy with because it comes with 15 unnecessary methods I have to implement.

Is there a more elegant way to solve this, something that's closer to compile time casting? One where the method would either succeed or throw a run time exception depending on if DerivedClass1 had a DerivedClass2 Cast Operator. Something more like:

```
Public Static BaseClass ConvertTo(BaseClass bc, Type type) {
     //First down cast it to bc, then sideways cast it to type.
     return (type)((bc.GetType())bc)
}
```

Comment: So you're going to do the work in a user-defined conversion, and you just want to find that and execute it via reflection?

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to have copies of similar structures? Automapper might be more usefull that whatever it is you are trying todo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for reflection over user-defined conversion operators. You can get at those with reflection by asking for public static methods and filtering to ones called `op_explicit` or `op_implicit`, with the right parameter and return types, and including `MethodAttributes.SpecialName`. Then just invoke the method as normal.

Here's some sample code I've whipped up quickly - you may well want to add more checks for robustness, include conversions to derived types or from base types, etc... but it's a start:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

class Foo
{
    public int Value { get; set; }        
    public static explicit operator Bar(Foo x) => new Bar { Value = x.Value };
    public static explicit operator Foo(Bar x) => new Foo { Value = x.Value };
}

class Bar
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo { Value = 10 };
        var bar = Convert<Bar>(foo);
        Console.WriteLine(bar.Value);
        foo = Convert<Foo>(bar);
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Value);        
    }

    public static T Convert<T>(object source)
    {
        var conversion = FindConversion(source.GetType(), typeof(T));
        if (conversion == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No conversion found");
        }
        return (T) conversion.Invoke(null, new[] { source });
    }

    private static MethodInfo FindConversion(Type fromType, Type toType)
    {
        var expectedParameterTypes = new[] { fromType };
        var methods = from type in new[] { fromType, toType }
                      from method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                      where method.Name == "op_Explicit" || method.Name == "op_Implicit"
                      where (method.Attributes & MethodAttributes.SpecialName) != 0
                      where method.ReturnType == toType
                      where method.GetParameters()
                                  .Select(p => p.ParameterType)
                                  .SequenceEqual(expectedParameterTypes)
                      select method;
        return methods.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.